# converting .h264 to other video formats

Tags: h264

How do I convert(compile?) h264 video from raspivid to a usable format?
I have tried using various video conversion programs in windows but none recognize the h254 format.

Comment: Have you checked out the raspivid doc? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspivid.md

Comment: This question does not belong to Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Use Handbrake it does conversion to h265 video without problems.

https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php

If wanting to do it manually on a desktop machine I have a bash script that does exactly the same using ffmpeg like most all them type of open source programs do. I use for just this purpose it is rather large to put here so I made a pastebin of it. It is easy enough to change the bit rate values to your desired values in it.

https://pastebin.com/Q2V8cPVY

If you do the script on the Pi it is going to take basically forever as it has so little processor power available for this type of activity. It is best done on a desktop machine with the ffmepg and the mkvtoolnix installed on Linux machine, so you get the required commands.